# having Missing required parameters for [Route everytime I add URL parameter in route

Tags: laravel

Hi I have a URL parameter in my order.index

```
<a href="/order-payments/create/{{$order->id}}"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></a>
```

I am passing the id to my order-payments.create. But every time I add the {id} in route

```
Route::get('/order-payments/create/{id}', 'OrderpaymentsController@create')->name('order-payments.create');
```

it gives me this error

[image]

This error is showing in my entire page even in other pages.

What do you think it causing this issue? thanks in advance!

### UPDATE

here's my store and create function in my OrderpaymentsController

```
public function create()
{
    return view('order-payments.create', compact('orderpayments'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // $orderpayments = Orderpayments::create($request->only('title'));
    // return redirect(route('order-payments.index'));

    $order = Orders::all('grandtotal','currency_id','company_id','id');
    $company = Companies::all('comp_name','id');
    $currency = Currencies::all('name','acronym','id');
    $banks = Banks::all('name','acronym','id');

    // dd($currency['name']);

    return view('order-payments.create', compact('orderpayments'))
        ->with('currency', $currency)
        ->with('banks', $banks)
        ->with('order', $order)
        ->with('company', $company)
        ->with('orderId', $order->id);

    // return view('order-payments.create');
}
```

Comment: Can you share youre create method into OrderpaymentsController*

Comment: Check to see if there are any other references to this route in your view. You might be missing to pass a parameter in other references to this routes in your view.

Comment: Hi @Saromase I just updated my question

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? In the `Create` method  you need to pass parameter and you are using that method to open create a page so why need id in this method?

use show method

Comment: pass id to the method create

Comment: Hi @bhavinjr. I am trying to pass the ID of the ORDER to order-payment.create so that I can grab the ORDER ID and its grand total.

Comment: @LitoLozada check my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{ route('order-payments.create', $order->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></a>
```

Make sure you get `$order->id` in blade file

`OrderpaymentsController.php`

```
public function create($order_id)
{
    $orderpayments = OrderPayment::find($order_id); //your query
    return view('order-payments.create', compact('orderpayments'));
}
```

Comment: my route should look like this right? Route::get('/order-payments/create/{order_id}', 'OrderpaymentsController@create')->name('order-payments.create');

Comment: Yes, and you give an id to the route, so on the controller you need to catch it.

Comment: @LitoLozada yes, you have to handle `order_id` in create method based on your logic

Comment: upon using route('order-payments.create', $order_id) I am receiving this /order-payments/create?3 so In my route i done this, Route::get('/order-payments/create?{order_id}', 'OrderpaymentsController@create')->name('order-payments.create'); But what I really notice is that whenever I add extension in /create in route I am receiving the error -- Missing required parameters for [Route: order-payments.create] [URI: order-payments/create/{order_id}].

Comment: `Route::get('/order-payments/create/{order_id}', 'OrderpaymentsController@create')->name('order-payments.create');`  remove `?`  from your route

Comment: yes currently that's my route look like, Route::get('/order-payments/create/{order_id}', 'OrderpaymentsController@create')->name('order-payments.create'); still having the"Missing required parameters for [Route: " error

Comment: should be work. check route list using: `php artisan route:list` check your URI and method name is proper or not.  and do one more thing `php artisan route:clear` remove cache file if exists

Comment: Hi the route is there. I also notice that if i type directly the route like, http://localhost:8000/orderPayments/create/3 the create page (which is currently blank) is showing. but the rest of the routes are having the said issues. I am also using chore Incognito

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route) helper to generate URLs. This will make sure the urls are consistent with the ones defined in you route files.

```
<a href="{{ route('order-payments.create', [$order->id]) }}"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give id to the method

```
public function create($id)
{
   return view('order-payments.create', compact('orderpayments'));
}
```